# Search records between two dates - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to create a search that returns records between two dates (today and a future date).

I can get it to return several records no problem  if I use the following code in my model (film.rb):

```
def self.date_search(search_string)
    self.where("release_date >= ?", search_string  )
```

However, when I try something like the following, I receive syntax errors:

```
    def self.date_search(search_string)
       date = Date.today
       self.where("release_date = created_at > date.strftime("%F") AND created_at < ?  ", search_string  )
```

I am still very new to Ruby so any help sorting out my syntax and code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try:   `where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?  ", date.strftime("%F"), search_string )`

Comment: convert `search_string` to date object then `self.where(:release_date => date.strftime("%F").beginning_of_day..search_string.end_of_day)`

Comment: I tried this which does run but unfortunately does not return any records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def self.date_search(search_string)
  self.where({release_date: Time.now..search_string})
end
```

This will give you entries where release_date is between the current time and the search_string (inclusive of the search string since you use two dots(..), it would be exclusive of the search string if you used three dots (...)

Comment: I tried the above but get a syntax error, unexpected (:)

Comment: Is release date a column in your database? If so, try the edited answer above

Comment: Answer from BigRon gave the solution....I just had to replace Time.now with date.strftime("%F") and set date as a variable = Date.today so the correct date format is recognised by the database